# Debezium timestamp issue, unable to convert into local timezone

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, cdc, debezium

We have done some set up to replicate mysql using debezium . The timestamp fields are getting converted into UTC timezone but our systems are in CST timezone . It is giving UTC timestamp in our transforms classes. We are unable to convert into CST timezone . Is there a way to not to convert into UTC timezone or can we convert it back to CST timezone .

Comment: **Why** are you unable to convert? **Where** are you converting? Might I suggest making everything UTC?

Answer (score 0):

there is a new SPI for public consumption you can use to customize the conversion handling accroding to your requirements - https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/development/converters.html

Answer (score 0):

for MySQL, I have implemented UTCtimestamp convertor (convert timestamp fields from UTC to local) Using SPI.
https://github.com/aminkr/UTCTimestampConverter

Comment: You could improve your answer by showing us some code.